# Datepicker partially blocked by footer

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am not really proficient in such thing, thus hopefully someone may help me with this. I have this particular problem that the footer have block the datepicker shown in the image. I am using sticky footer which is not the result I desire, thus I never label the `footer` class in my `<div>`.

[image]

This is my current code:

```
<div class =" navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<div class ="container">
    <font size="3" color="white"><p class="paddingAll">Copyright &#169 2015</p></font>

</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 55px;
}
```

What I would like to have is to make the footer bar push down and reveal the whole datepicker and will close the remaining gap when the datepicker is being kept away.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-bottom` instead of `margin-bottom`
CSS:

```
body {
      padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a good cheat to show the whole datepicker by manipulating with space

Answer (score 0):

Remove relative position from bottom class cos any relative position without z-index is more power than absolute without z-index so your .bottom is over your calendar suppose.

Comment: the last 2 row of datepicker apparently blocked by the footer

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative; z-index:1;` to datepicker class.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10383197)

Comment: @M.Deinum, it's exactly the anser. If you think it's not, you have to clarify that.

Comment: Well it is the answer, correct, but you might want to extend it a little on the why/how...